# Openshift SpringBoot + Wildfly always exceeding quota

Tags: spring, jboss, openshift, wildfly

Anyone here also using Openshift + SpringBoot + Wildfly?
I wanna ask how you deal with this.

The space occupied by my wildfly application is 0.8GB.
But after 1 day, it will exceed quota to 1GB. Of course the possible solution is to run `app-tidy` and it would clean up some space, but come pass another day it would exceed quota again.

Any workaround for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I deactivated the Wildfly logging, and the issue never came back again.

In standalone.xml:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:logging:2.0">
            <add-logging-api-dependencies value="false"/>
            <use-deployment-logging-config value="false"/>
            ...
```

Comment: 200 Mb in a day is a lot of logging. I wouldn't expect Wildfly or SpringBoot to log that much.

Answer (score 0):

Your options are limited since the free plan comes with only 1GB of space.  You will need to upgrade to either the Silver or Bronze plan and add some storage to your application.